# Function `serialize` in jQuery is not working

Tags: html, jquery, forms, serialization

I have used `serialize` function lots of times but this one time is not working properly, it returns an empty array. I can't spot any error within the code. I would appreciate any help. It seems like the Form is empty or is not reading the fields on the form. Here is the code which uses some PHP to generate the table which contains all the fields for the form:

```
                <form id="formReporte" >         
                    <div id="kt_subscriptions_table_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper 
                         dtbootstrap4 no-footer">
                            
                                <table class="table align-middle table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5 dataTable no-footer table2excel" id="kt_table" data-tableName="Test Table 1">
                                    <!--begin::Table head-->
                                    <thead>
                                        <!--begin::Table row-->
                                        
                                        <tr class="text-muted fw-bold fs-7 text-uppercase gs-0">
                                        
                                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_subscriptions_table">Fecha</th>
                                            <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_subscriptions_table">Orden #</th>
                                            <th class=" sorting sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_subscriptions_table" >Nombre</th>
                                            <th class=" sorting sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="kt_subscriptions_table" >Apellido</th>
                                        
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                        <!--end::Table row-->
                                    </thead>
                                    <!--end::Table head-->
                                    <!--begin::Table body-->
                                    <tbody class="text-gray-600 fw-semibold fs-7">
                                        
                                        <?php
                                        
                                           $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tblordenes $searchQuery ORDER BY fecha_orden DESC ");
                                            $cont = $query->num_rows;
                                            
                                            $subtotal = 0;
                                            $total = 0;
                                            $envio = 0;
                                            $tax = 0;
                                            
                                            $i = 0;
                                            
                                            if($cont>0){
                                             while($row= $query->fetch_array())
                                             {
                                                 
                                                $date = date_create($row['fecha_orden']);
                                                $formatdate = date_format($date, "d/m/Y");
                                                
                                                $qty_txt1 = 'text-dark';
                                                
                                                
                                                $fname = get_user_detail('nombre', $row['idUsuario']);
                                                $lname = get_user_detail('apellido', $row['idUsuario']);
                                                
                                                $fullname = $fname.' '.$lname;
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                    ?>
                                    
                                      
                                     <tr class="odd">
                                            
                                            <!--begin::Fecha=-->
                                            <td class="">
                                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                        <?php echo $formatdate; ?>
                                                
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Fecha=-->
                                            <!--begin::Orden #=-->
                                            <td class="text-left pe-0">
                                                <span class="fw-bold"><?php echo $row['num_orden']; ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="num_orden_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['num_orden']; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Orden #=-->
                                            <!--begin::Name=-->
                                            <td class="text-left pe-0 sorting_1">
                                                
                                                <span class="fw-bold ms-3"><?php echo $fname; ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="fname_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Name=-->
                                            <!--begin::LName=-->
                                            <td class="text-left pe-0 sorting_1">
                                                
                                                <span class="fw-bold ms-3"><?php echo $lname; ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="lname_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::LName=-->
                                            
                                            <!--end::LName=-->
                                            <!--begin::Sub-Total=-->
                                            <td class="text-end subtotal">
                                                <span class="fw-bold ">$<?php echo number_format($row['monto_subtotal'],2,'.',','); ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="monto_subtotal_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['monto_subtotal']; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Sub-Total=-->
                                            <!--begin::Envio=-->
                                            <td class="text-end">
                                                <span class="fw-bold ">$<?php echo number_format($row['monto_envio'],2,'.',','); ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="monto_envio_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['monto_envio']; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--begin::=-->
                                            <!--end::Tax=-->
                                            <td class="text-end">
                                                <span class="fw-bold ">$<?php echo number_format($row['monto_tax'],2,'.',','); ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="monto_tax_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['monto_tax']; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Taxx=-->
                                            <!--begin::Total=-->
                                            <td class="text-end">
                                                <span class="fw-bold ">$<?php echo number_format($row['monto_total'],2,'.',','); ?></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="monto_total_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['monto_total']; ?>">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--end::Total=-->
                                            
                                        </tr>
                                  
                                         <?php 
                                           $i++;
                                         } 
                                            }
                                            
                                             ?>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="contador" id="contador" value="<?php echo $cont;?>"> 
                                        </tbody>
                                        
                                    <!--end::Table body-->
                                    <tfoot>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>TOTAL</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        
                                       </tr>
                                     </tfoot>
                                    
                                </table>
                                <!--end::Table-->
                                
                                <!--begin::Excel Button-->
                                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end" data-kt-subscription-table-toolbar="base">
                                       
                                        <a href="#"  id="btn_guardar_reporte" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                    Generar Reporte Z</a>
                                        <!--end::Excel Button-->
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
```

and this is the jQuery script:

```
$("#btn_guardar_reporte").on('click', function(){
           
           var url = 'action_guardar_reporteZ.php';
          
           var data = $('#formReporte').serialize();
           
           alert(data);
        
             $.ajax({
                    
                      type : 'POST',
                      url  : url,
                      data: data,
                      success :  function(response)
                      {      
                        alert(response);
                     
                     }
                   });
          
           
       })
```

When I check the alert box with the data it shows up empty.

Comment: The browser doesn't care about php. How does the rendered html look like?

Comment: it renders a table with the database values

Comment: What I meant is: update the code in your question.